# What does "he came galloping up" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> He came galloping up and halted.

Does "he came galloping up" mean the person was riding a horse? Was the person coming towards the speaker?

I just wonder if the man was riding a horse, and if he was coming near the speaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Maybe.

The galloping part can mean one of two things: Either;

1. The 'he' was on a horse; or
2. The 'he' was actually walking in a galloping fashion, i.e. like skipping.

Of the two, the first is more likely. You're correct about the 'he' coming toward the speaker.

Comment: The answer to the coming-toward-the-speaker is a "maybe" as well. It's contextual. _The knight saw the castle in the distance. Darkness was closing in all around him. As he neared the castle, he noticed the drawbridge was closed, and there would be no way across the moat. He came galloping up and halted, then called to sentry. "Lower the bridge!" he demanded._ Here, "galloping up" means coming toward the castle, not the narrator.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context. If it is known or inferred that he is riding a horse, then the primary sense of *[gallop](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=gallop)* applies, i.e. to ride a horse at a gallop, moving at a fast gait in which all four feet are simultaneously off the ground during each stride.

Otherwise, it the metaphorical sense applies, i.e. to move quickly, and not necessarily in imitation of a horse's gait at that. He could also have come *flying* or *charging* or *blazing* or *rocketing*, for example, without the need of an airplane, elephant, gun, or rocket.